# Trouble with DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

I am trying to solve this equation:

```
DSolve[{y''[x] + y'[x]* 0.002 + 4*Sin[2*y[x]] == 0, 
  y[0] == 0.005*n*(30 - n), y'[0] == 0 }, y[x], x]
```

However, it keeps giving this result:

```
Solve::ifun :
Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found;
use Reduce for complete solution information.
```

Comment: That's a warning message and not a result. What do you get as the actual output?

Comment: I don't know why my output is also my input ? is it because it can not solve my equation?

Comment: That means that Mma does not know the result. Nothing to do. Not all equations exhibit a solution that can be expressed in analytical functions, the more, the dissipative version of the Sine-Gordon. Try to solve it numerically.

Answer (score 1):

Do the numerical version

```
ndsol = NDSolve[{Derivative[2, 0][y][x, n] + 
 Derivative[1, 0][y][x, n]*0.002 + 4*Sin[2*y[x, n]] == 0, 
    y[0, n] == 0.005*n*(30 - n), Derivative[1, 0][y][0, n] == 0}, 
    y, {x, -10, 10}, {n, -40, 50}]

Plot3D[y[x, n] /. First@ndsol, {x, -10, 10}, {n, -40, 50}, 
    ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Following Alexei Boulbitch's hint:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{y''[x] + y'[x]*0.002 + 4*Sin[2*y[x]] == 0, 
       y[0] == 0.005*n*(30 - n), y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 1}, {n}]

Plot[Evaluate[Table[y[n][x] /. sol, {n, -1, 1, .5}]], {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> {# & @@@ Range[-1, 1, 0.5]}]
```

[image]